# I need to return one of two responses (leave blank or add text) in a cell based on information in two different cells

Tags: excel-formula

I need to determine if a product has shipped based on two different cells that may or may not have a date or be empty.

Basically I have today's date, =Today(), in cell A1.  Starting in Row 10 I have information that includes products with ship dates.  I need to list if the product has shipped or not in Column L.  Ship date if known is in column K, if it's not known the cell in column K is empty.  What I need to achieve is, if the cell in column K is blank the cell in column L should also be blank, if the date in column K is today's date or past (referenced to cell A1) then column L should read "Shipped", if the date in column K is in the future the cell in column L should read "Forecast".

I am having trouble nesting the criteria.  I've used =IF(K10<=$A$1,"Shipped","Forecast") which tells me if it shipped or is still Forecast to ship but does not take into consideration a blank cell in column K (a blank cell currently shows it has shipped) where I don't know the ship date yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=IF(K10="","",IF(K10<=$A$1,"Shipped","Forecast"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one IF() with AND() for the same :

```
=IF(AND(K10<>"",K10<=$A$1),"Shipped","Forecast")
```

Comment: Worked great except if K10 was blank it returned "Forecast", where I wanted it left blank.  Big Ben's suggestion did exactly as I wanted.  Thanks for the response, gave a little more insight on an alternative.  Cheers!

Comment: @Greg - to be fair, your question title was slightly misleading - there were actually  3 possible options to return (blank, shipped, or forecast).